# Computational comparison in solving two optimization problems

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, nonlinear-optimization, specific-calculation

Can I get some inputs on whether the following two optimization problems are computationally the same, or one of the problems is easier to solve computationally than the other, such as, finding their optimal solutions?

Given $A_i \in S^n, i = 1, \ldots, m$, the two optimization problems are given as follows:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\max_{q \in \Re^n, \| q \| = 1} \lambda_{\min}\left( \sum_{i=1}^m (q^T A_i q) A_i \right) = \max_{q \in \Re^n, \| q \| = 1} \min_{q_1 \in \Re^n, \| q_1 \| = 1} \left( \sum_{i=1}^m (q^T A_i q)(q_1^T A_i q_1) \right),
\end{eqnarray*}
and
\begin{eqnarray*}
\max_{|y_i| \leq 1, i = 1, \ldots, m} \lambda_{\min} \left( \sum_{i=1}^m y_i A_i \right) = \max_{|y_i| \leq 1, i = 1, \ldots, m} \min_{q_1 \in \Re^n, \| q_1 \| = 1} \left( \sum_{i=1}^m y_i (q_1^T A_i q_1) \right).
\end{eqnarray*}
Note that $\lambda_{\min}(S)$, where $S \in S^n$, stands for the smallest eigenvalue of $S$.